# Finding Element with Random ID [Python/Selenium]

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

What the problem is:
I'm new to Selenium and I'm trying to find an element on  a webpage. The background is I want to write a script so that it can help me create instance on Oracle cloud. On the page where I have to select *Compartment*, I need to input my root name. I just can't find the input box.
[image: The webpage with code]
I beleive the element is the one highlighted, corresponding to the "Choose a compartment" on the left side of the webpage, but the id is random.

What I tried:
To name a few, I tried
`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="active_compartment_select-dc369079-e95a-2176-f8e4-6ee9c16fe105_trigger"]/ul/li/input')`

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/aside/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/a/ul/li/input')`

I also tried
`By.CLASS_NAME, 'dropdown-trigger arrow bottom'`, it showed nothing;
`By.XPATH, //div[contains(@id, 'active_compartment_select')]`, it showed nothing.
I even tried `find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'input')` and there's still no such element in the returned list.
I tried basically all the suggestions I could find on stackoverflow, but it still shows no such element exception.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is inside an iframe, I checked my Oracle cloud account, try this, its working:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "sandbox-compute-container")))

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[starts-with(@id,'active_compartment_select-')]//a").click()
```

Comment: Hi Abi, thank you for your suggestion, but unfortunately it still doesn't work. Do I need to 
 do any modifications to your code? I just copy and paste it, and still the NoSuchElementException error

Comment: try now, updated the XPath.

Comment: I'm  sorry  but still no... I may not find the correct element to input my name, but it is wierd that I can't find the element, even if the wrong one...

Comment: It is inside an iframe,  I checked my Oracle cloud account, updated the code, check it.

Comment: Hi Abi! Yes, it wworks! Thank you so much. There are still many things to learn in scraping for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find the dropdown "Compartment", right?
You can find it using this xpath: `driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[@placeholder="Choose a compartment"]')`

Comment: Hi Eugeny, thank you for your suggestion, but still the NoSuchElementException...  I suspect that it is because Selenium even can't find the input tag, because I also tried `find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'input')`,which still didn't have the input field I want in the returned list.

Comment: Can you check if there are any `iframe` tags in the source? It is possible that all the elements are in a separate iframe and you need to switch to it.

Comment: Hi Eugeny, thank you so much for your suggestion. Yes, it is  in an `ifram` and the other answer provided the code. I tried and it worked.  Thank you!